# Numpy List Comprehension vs Frompyfunc

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
def getneighbors(cpdlist,rxnid):
 tmplist2 = []
 for cpd in cpdlist:
     #tmp = [x for x in self.traindf if cpd in x[1]]
     #tmplist = [x[1] for x in tmp if rxnid != x[0]]

     f = np.frompyfunc(lambda x: cpd in x,1,1)
     tmp = traindf[np.where(f(self.traindf))[0]]
     tmplist2 = tmplist2 + [x[1] for x in tmp if rxnid != x[0]]
 rloc = [x.split('/') for x in tmplist2]
 flat2 = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(rloc2))
```

traindf would look like

```
array([['RXN-A','WATER/Glucopyranose',
       'RXN-B','1-3-beta-D-Glucans',
       'RXN-C','WATER/HYDROGEN-PEROXIDE'
       'RXN-D','HYDROGEN-PEROXIDE'
       'RXN-E','Glucopyranose/NADPH']]
```

cpdlist = ['WATER','Glucopyranose']

rxnid = 'RXN-A'

tmplist2 would be ['WATER/HYDROGEN-PEROXIDE','Glucopyranose/NADPH']

flat2 would be ['WATER','HYDROGEN-PEROXIDE','Glucopyranose','NADPH']

QUESTION:
My code above does work but it takes 40 seconds because I am recursively going through this function each iteration of a large loop. Is there any way I should optimize this function above so my program will run much faster? I have concluded that this section is the bottleneck.

I am also new to numpy because pandas str.contains was too slow for this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: numpy doesn't have `apply`.  frompyfunc can be up 2x faster than a comprehension, that's all.  But it can't skip elements like a comprehension (no `if` clause)

Comment: Thanks so much! Any ideas on how to get rid of that for loop, or is there no way to do that?

Comment: Could you please post a complete example. Add some value for `cpdlist` and `rxnid`. And what you would like to see.

Comment: I posted a more complete example that's more straightforward.